# looping over PHP array

Tags: php

I am not a PHP dev. I was working with google API and the backend I am using is PHP. I am working with an example which returns locations within certain distance of the given zipcode. The result set returned from PHP is of following format..

```
    Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[id] => 554
[postcode] => 1225
[suburb] => Royal Exchange
[aus_post_name] => ROYAL EXCHANGE
[state] => NSW
[lat] => -33.864393
[lon] => 151.209608
)

[1] => Array
(
[id] => 559
[postcode] => 1230
[suburb] => Queen Victoria Building
[aus_post_name] => QUEEN VICTORIA BUILDING
[state] => NSW
[lat] => -33.872049
[lon] => 151.206428
)

[2] => Array
(
[id] => 714
[postcode] => 2000
[suburb] => Barangaroo
[aus_post_name] => BARANGAROO
[state] => NSW
[lat] => -33.858315
[lon] => 151.203519
)

[3] => Array
(
[id] => 715
[postcode] => 2000
[suburb] => Dawes Point
[aus_post_name] => DAWES POINT
[state] => NSW
[lat] => -33.855601
[lon] => 151.20822
)
```

How do I loop over the result set, and get the values, for example for state and suburb?

Comment: Show some code, as @JackManey says.

Comment: never mind...got the answer on my own. go ahead vote it and close it..

Answer (score 3):

Use a [for loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) or [foreach loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

```
foreach ($bigarray as $row) {
    echo $row['suburb'];  // suburb
    echo $row['state'];   // state
}
```

Comment: Uh what? It ought to be `foreach($bigarray as $row)`, no? Your current code makes no sense. Not downvoting cause its a small mistake, but not upvoting cause it's wrong for now.

Answer (score 0):

Use for loop. It is best way to fetch the state and suburb data.. The following code will help you..

```
$arr_var=Array
(
     0 => Array
     (
       'id' => 554,
       'postcode' => 1225,
       'suburb' => 'Royal Exchange',
       'aus_post_name' =>'ROYAL EXCHANGE',
       'state' => 'NSW',
       'lat' => -33.864393,
       'lon' => 151.209608
    ),

1 => Array
   (
       'id' => 559,
       'postcode' => 1230,
       'suburb' => 'Queen Victoria Building',
       'aus_post_name' => 'QUEEN VICTORIA BUILDING',
       'state' => 'NSW',
       'lat' => -33.872049,
      'lon' => 151.206428,
   )
);

for($i=0;count($arr_var)>$i;$i++)
{
    echo " state : ".$arr_var[$i]['state'];
    echo " suburb : ".$arr_var[$i]['suburb'];
}
```